# @_exported import but in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, import, swift-package-manager, swift-package

Swift has an interesting keyword, which can be declared in the `ModuleA`:

```
@_exported import Foundation
```

Then, when in some other module (e.g. `ModuleB`) I import the `ModuleA`:

```
import ModuleA

let currentDate = Date() // using a Foundation struct
```

... I'm able to use also the types from the `Foundation` even though I'm not importing it with an `import` statement. It's being automatically imported as it has been declared as `@_exported` in the `ModuleA`.

Now I'd like to have a similar behavior in Objective-C.

Given:

- 3 Targets: `TargetA` (Swift), `ProtocolTarget`(Swift with `@objc` keyword annotated types) and `TargetB` (ObjC)
- I'd like to make the `ProtocolTarget` implicitly imported, so that when the `TargetB` imports `TargetA`, all of the methods from the `ProtocolTarget` should become also available inside the `TargetA`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would just import the headers for `ProtocolTarget` into your umbrella headers for `TargetA` and `TargetB`. See how `Cocoa` does it for example (it imports the headers for Foundation, AppKit, and CoreData)

Comment: Could you please pinpoint to the file of "how Cocoa does it"?

Comment: Command click on the `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` in `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in one of your Objective C files

Comment: Are you restricted to use modules only? If not, why not just rely on transitive `#import` expression?

Comment: Updated my question. Actually, I am restricted to modules only, since the `ProtocolTarget` turned out to be a Swift target with `@objc` annotated keywords. Now I'd like to achieve a behavior similar to how Swift modules work.